# SQL Left Join of Two Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working with joining two tables from my database. But I'm getting problem in showing the data from the second table.

My first table has data which have multiple **itemcode** but I want to display it once in the page so used GROUP BY in the query. On my second table there are also multiple **itemcode** but this time I want to show the data on the page. but it's not showing, is it because of the GROUP BY. Can you please help me identify what's the problem in the query. thanks.

Here's the sample table I want to look like.

[image]

Here's my query(**I simplified it):

```
SELECT  mcc.ALL, mva.ALL
FROM  `mtrl_cons_cost` mcc
LEFT JOIN material_value_aging mva ON mcc.itemcode = mva.item_code
GROUP BY  mcc.site_cons , mcc.itemcode, mcc.deptcode , mcc.item_desc,  mcc.subinv_code ,  mcc.item_uom
```

**Update**
This is the whole code. Please see.

```
$site = "112";
$date1 = date("Y-m");
$date2 = date("Y-m", strtotime("-1 month") ) ;
$date3 = date("Y-m", strtotime("-2 month") ) ;
$date1s = date("Ym");
$date2s = date("Ym", strtotime("-1 month") ) ;
$date3s = date("Ym", strtotime("-2 month") ) ;

echo "<form>";
echo "<h2>CONSUMPTION REPORT AND MATERIAL VALUE AGING AS OF $date1</h2>";
echo "<table border=5>";

echo "<tr class=header bgcolor=#adff2f rowspan=2>";

echo "<th>SITE</th>";
echo "<th>DEPT</th>";
echo "<th>ITEM CODE</th>";
echo "<th>DESCRIPTION</th>";
echo "<th>ITEM TYPE</th>";
echo "<th>UOM</th>";
echo "<th>{$date1} QUANTITY</th>";
echo "<th>{$date1} COST</th>";
echo "<th>{$date2} QUANTITY</th>";
echo "<th>{$date2} COST</th>";
echo "<th>{$date3} QUANTITY</th>";
echo "<th>{$date3} COST</th>";

echo "<th bgcolor=yellow></th>";

/*** Material Value Aging ***/
//echo "<th>SITE</th>";
echo "<th>CUSTOMER PN</th>";
//echo "<th>ITEM CODE</th>";
echo "<th>TYPE</th>";
echo "<th>UOM</th>";
echo "<th>DESCRIPTION</th>";
//echo "<th>DEPT CODE</th>";
echo "<th>SUB</th>";
echo "<th>RECEIVED DATE</th>";
echo "<th>AGE</th>";
echo "<th>LOT SERIAL</th>";
echo "<th>QUANTITY</th>";
echo "<th>VALUE IN USD</th>";
echo "<th>A30 0-30DAYS</th>";
echo "<th>A60 31-60DAYS</th>";
echo "<th>A90 61-90DAYS</th>";
echo "<th>A120 91-120DAYS</th>";
echo "<th>A180 121-180DAYS</th>";
echo "<th>ABOVE 180 DAYS</th>";

echo "</tr>";


$query="
SELECT  mcc.site_cons ,  mcc.deptcode ,  mcc.itemcode ,  mcc.item_desc ,  mcc.subinv_code ,  mcc.item_uom , SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date1'
THEN  mcc.qty 
END ) AS  'qty_$date1', SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date1s'
THEN  mcc.total_cost 
END ) AS  'tot_cost_$date1s', SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date2'
THEN  mcc.qty 
END ) AS  'qty_$date2', SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date2s'
THEN  mcc.total_cost
END ) AS  'tot_cost_$date2s', SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date3'
THEN  mcc.qty 
END ) AS  'qty_$date3', SUM( 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(  mcc.trans_date ,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$date3s'
THEN  mcc.total_cost 
END ) AS  'tot_cost_$date3s', mva.*
FROM  `mtrl_cons_cost` mcc
LEFT JOIN material_value_aging mva ON mcc.itemcode = mva.item_code 
WHERE  mcc.site_cons LIKE  '$site' 
GROUP BY  mcc.site_cons , mcc.itemcode, mcc.deptcode , mcc.item_desc,  mcc.subinv_code ,  mcc.item_uom
";

//
$conn = dbConnect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt-> execute();


while($getrow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $site_cr = $getrow['site_cons'];
    $deptcode_cr = $getrow['deptcode'];
    $itemcode_cr = $getrow['itemcode'];
    $itemdesc_cr = $getrow['item_desc'];
    $subinvcode_cr = $getrow['subinv_code'];
    $itemuom_cr = $getrow['item_uom'];
    $qtydate1s_cr = $getrow['qty_$date1s'];
    $costdate1s_cr = $getrow['tot_cost_$date1s'];
    $qtydate2s_cr = $getrow['qty_$date2s'];
    $costdate2s_cr = $getrow['tot_cost_$date2s'];
    $qtydate3s_cr = $getrow['qty_$date3s'];
    $costdate3s_cr = $getrow['tot_cost_$date3s'];

    $sitec = $getrow['site'];
    $cust_pn = $getrow['customer_pn'];
    $itemcode = $getrow['item_code'];
    $itemtype = $getrow['item_type'];
    $UOM = $getrow['uom'];
    $desc = $getrow['description'];
    $deptcode = $getrow['dept_code'];
    $subcode = $getrow['subinventory_code'];
    $received_Date = $getrow['received_date'];
    $age = $getrow['age'];
    $lot_no = $getrow['lot_number'];
    $qty = $getrow['qty'];
    $ttl_val = $getrow['ttl_value'];

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>{$site_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$deptcode_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$itemcode_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$itemdesc_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$subinvcode_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$itemuom_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$qtydate1s_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$costdate1s_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$qtydate2s_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$costdate2s_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$qtydate3s_cr}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$costdate3s_cr}</td>";

    echo "<td bgcolor=yellow>&nbsp;</td>";

    //echo "<td>{$sitec}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$cust_pn}</td>";
    //echo "<td>{$itemcode}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$itemtype}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$UOM}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$desc}</td>";
    //echo "<td>{$deptcode}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$subcode}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$received_Date}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$age}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$lot_no}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$qty}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$ttl_val}</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

}

$conn=null;

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Table 1:mtrl_cons_cost

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mtrl_cons_cost` (
  `site_cons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deptcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trans_date` date NOT NULL,
  `itemcode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `item_desc` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `subinv_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `item_uom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL,
  `total_cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2: material_value_aging

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `material_value_aging` (
  `site` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `customer_pn` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `uom` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dept_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subinventory_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `received_date` date NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lot_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `ttl_value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please stick to posting data in the text format and refrain from posting images.

Comment: @SameerMirji sorry. it's just for a reference.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you perform a `GROUP BY my_columns`, you will only have one line per combination of your columns values. And all other selected columns (the ones not in the `GROUP BY`) are chosen from a random row of each group (maybe the first one, I don't remember). Here your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` allows lines to have no `mva` columns at all.

`GROUP BY` is made to work with aggregations, like `COUNT`, `SUM` or `MAX`. Just remove your `GROUP BY` and use `ORDER BY` instead. You'll have nicely sorted lines - with duplicate informations on the left - and you just need to iterate over your sorted results to identify your groups iteratively.

```
 SELECT  mcc.ALL, mva.ALL
 FROM  `mtrl_cons_cost` mcc
 LEFT JOIN material_value_aging mva ON mcc.itemcode = mva.item_code
 ORDER BY  mcc.site_cons , mcc.itemcode, mcc.deptcode , mcc.item_desc,  mcc.subinv_code ,  mcc.item_uom
```

Comment: actually I have tried to use ORDER BY but it only returns 1 row with no matching data on the second table

Comment: Can you add the schema of your two tables ?

Comment: Well I don't know why you have empty lines then. Maybe your data doesn't have any mva.item_code equal to any mcc.itemcode. Have you tried a simple `INNER JOIN` to se if you get any results ?